# DropDownList Client Side Validation is validating when it should not be. (MVC3, Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I am still learning MVC3 and Razor, so this is perhaps a simple question.

On a view I have a DropDownList whose sole purpose is to help filter (via AJAX) a second drop down list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Segments", "-- select segment --")
```

There is a Segments property of the ViewModel that is defined as:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Segments { get; set; }
```

There is JavaScript that handles the change event for this DropDownList and populates another DropDownList with appropriate values. That other DropDownList is defined like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.fafhProdRecId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- select product recommendation --")
```

This all works fine until I submit. When I submit, I get a validation error on the Segments drop down list!

Now -- there should be absolutely NO validation on the segments DropDownList -- there shouldn't be any client side validation on EITHER drop down list, for that matter.

But when I try to submit, I get the validation error message back:

**The value '1' is invalid.**

I have no idea why this is happening. 
I have no idea how to decorate the Segments property to say that it is NOT required. 
I have no idea how to tell the unobtrusive javascript validator that it is, in fact, being quite obtrusive.

Comment: Hey, didn't we all agree to have readable variable names? ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ViewModel class add [Bind(Exclude = "Segments")]

From: [Using Data Annotations for Model Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6)

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your Model has `fafhProdRecId` as nullable, I imagine it's declared as:

```
public int fafhProdRecId { get; set; }
```

change this to:

```
public int? fafhProdRecId { get; set; }
```

hopefully, that should resolve the issue as this effectively makes the model field nullable (assuming the db field **IS nullable** too of course).

Comment: the error (seems to be) on the segment, not the fafhProdRecId. I tried your change, though, and it seemed to make no difference. Still got the value '1' is invalid message on the Segments dropdown.